# Reading character-by-character - always reaching an invalid character

Tags: c, switch-statement, decimal, radix

I'm new to C and to the programming world. I've been requested to get a reversed number in base 20 and print out his conversion to decimal.
I know it's not the most efficient code out there, but that's the best I managed to do with my current knowledge.
When I run this program and input a number, I'm always getting the default case...
What am I missing?
Thank you :)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char x;
    int exponent= 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter a reversed number is base 20\n");
    scanf(" %c", &x);
    while (x != "\n") {
        switch (x) {
        case '0':sum += 0;
            break;
        case '1':sum += 1 * exponent;
            break;
        case '2':   sum += 2 * exponent;
            break;
        case '3':sum += 3 * exponent;
            break;
        case '4':sum += 4 * exponent;
            break;
        case '5':sum += 5 * exponent;
            break;
        case '6':sum += 6 * exponent;
            break;
        case '7':sum += 7 * exponent;
            break;
        case '8':sum += 8 * exponent;
            break;
        case '9':sum += 9 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'A':
        case 'a': sum += 10 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'b':sum += 11 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c' : sum += 12 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd': sum += 13 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e': sum += 14 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'f': sum += 15 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'g': sum += 16 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'H':
        case 'h': sum += 17 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'I':
        case 'i': sum += 18 * exponent;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'j': sum += 19 * exponent;
            break;
        default:flag++;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("Error! %c is not a valid digit in base 20", x);
            break;
        }
        else {
            exponent *= 20;;
            scanf("%c", &x);
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        printf(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you ignore the compiler warnings?

Comment: You are comparing a `char` with a string constant. You should compare it with a character constant (single quotes, not double quotes).

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &x);`-> `scanf("%c", &x);`, `x !=  "\n"` -> `x !=  '\n'`. `printf(sum)` -> `printf("%d\n", sum)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Why is it important that OP drop the space in the `scanf()` format string?

Comment: @einpoklum because otherwise we don't get the `\n`.

Comment: OT: the quantity of code inside the switch block can roughly be reduced by a factor of 7 or 8.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: But there's only a space in the first `scanf()`. So we do get the '\n'.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, you're right.

Comment: There's no need for the giant switch.  A very common idiom is to write: `sum += (x - '0') * exponent`.  That does not work for `aA-eE`, and for those you can write `sum += ( tolower(x) - 'a' + 10) * exponent`.  Two conditions is better than 20.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read your [compiler's warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/bETvMe)...:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:10:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   10 |     while (x != "\n") {
      |              ^~
<source>:10:14: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
<source>:77:16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   77 |         printf(sum);
      |                ^~~
      |                |
      |                int
In file included from <source>:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:332:43: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
  332 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

You're comparing `x` to a an address - the address of the string constant "\n" (that is located in some section of your program's memory space). You probably meant to compare `x` to '\n'.

Also, the `printf()` function takes a format string before the argument, so it should be `printf("%d\n", sum);` (to also print a newline character).

---

PS 1: Always compile your code with more warnings turned on, e.g. `gcc -W -Wall` (and perhaps other warning flags) for a better chance catch these kinds of typos and minor errors.

PS 2: As @Jabberwocky notes, your program could be made much shorter (with no loss of readability); and, on the other hand, you should always check the return value of `scanf()` and similar functions which may fail due to user input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char x;
    int exponent = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int num_scanned;
    printf("Enter a reversed number is base 20\n");
    num_scanned = scanf(" %c", &x);
    if (num_scanned != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (x != '\n') {
        int digit;
        if      (x >= '0' && x <= '9') { digit = x-'0'; }
        else if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'j') { digit = x-'a'; }
        else if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'J') { digit = x-'A'; }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c is not a valid digit in base 20.", x);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sum += digit * exponent;
        exponent *= 20;
        num_scanned = scanf("%c", &x);
        if (num_scanned != 1) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: For purposes of demonstration, you should almost certainly replace the scanf with a more idiomatic while/getchar loop.  Or, you *must* demonstrate checking the value returned by scanf to avoid the infinite loop on invalid input.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Fair enough.